# Linq to c++.net expression conversion

Tags: linq, visual-c++, c++-cli

Below is my linq expression:

ListName.Except(xxx)
         .Where(x => x.columnname != "xyz");

Can someone help in converting this expression to c++.net?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq methods in C++/CLI, but you cannot use the Lambda syntax. Instead, you need to turn it into a full-fledged method, and pass that as a delegate.

```
static bool NotBannedColumnName(ColumnObject x)
{
    return x.columnname != "xyz";
}

ListName.Except(xxx).Where(gcnew Func<TSource, bool>(&ThisClass::NotBannedColumnName));
```